# Haskell Cartesian product of infinite amount of infinite lists

Tags: haskell

Hi I want to ask if it is possible to create a Cartesian product of Infinite amount of infinite lists.

Sequence is a good function as example what I want. But I want it to work on Infinites.

I know how to do Cartesian of two infinite lists.

```
cartInf2 xs ys = xs >>= (\x ->
                 ys >>= (\y -> [[x,y]]))
```

Also I cant figure out how to do Cartesian of any amount of infinite list

Comment: Your `cartInf2` is equivalent to `cartInf2' (x:xs) ys = map (\y->[x,y]) ys`. Some pairs are never listed. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzmxqMQzL81IoaJYobJYwRZE29nZKmjEVCjo2nEpoINKmHQlUFohOrpCpzI2VlOTiwtmkLqCRoVVRbEmxLTcxAKQWl07sEKQIBdXbmJmHlAqJR9oekFRZl6JgopCSWJ2qoKRAZAFd5BCtJGeXqxCtDGQxKtSHVnl//8A "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: I'd start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Infinite_Cartesian_products).

Comment: There are uncountably many elements. It's guaranteed that some element will not be listed.

Comment: How do you plan to use such data structure, given that it'd be uncoutable? Maybe the problem you're trying to solve with this Cartesian product has a different, simpler/better solution.

Comment: Since the number of lists is infinite as well, this set is uncountable, hence there are elements that will *never* be emitted.

Comment: You might be looking for [`Control.Monad.Omega`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-omega-0.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Omega.html) or [`Control.Monad.WeightedSearch`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/weighted-search-0.1.0.1), if you want a sort of fair interleaving between infinitely many cases.

Comment: Can you show 5-6 initial elements of the desired cartesian product? Assume all input lists are `[1..]`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `cartInf` does not actually work.

```
ghci> take 100 $ cartInf2 [1..] [1..]
[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[1,7],[1,8],[1,9],[1,10],[1,11],[1,12], 
[1,13],[1,14],[1,15],[1,16],[1,17],[1,18],[1,19],[1,20],[1,21],[1,22],[1,23], 
[1,24],[1,25],[1,26],[1,27],[1,28],[1,29],[1,30],[1,31],[1,32],[1,33],[1,34], 
...
```

We will never reach a point where the first element is anything but `1`.  As @chi recommends you can use [`Control.Monad.Omega`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-omega-0.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Omega.html) or [`Control.Monad.WeightedSearch`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/weighted-search-0.1.0.1) if you want every pair to appear in the result eventually.

Secondly, the cartesian product of infinitely many lists is not countable (as long as they have at least two elements), as [proved by Cantor in 1891](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).  Suppose we had

```
allBoolLists :: [[Bool]]
allBoolLists = cartesianProduct (repeat [True,False])
```

which would be the list of "all infinite lists of booleans".  No such list can exist, because we can construct

```
bad :: [Bool]
bad = zipWith negateNth [0..] allBoolLists
    where
    -- negates the nth element of a list
    negateNth n xs = take n xs ++ not (xs !! n) ++ drop (n+1) xs
```

which differs from every element of `allBoolLists` -- it differs from the 0th element at position 0, the 1st element at position 1, and so on.